# Can I recover component instance without creating a fresh one?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In my component, I have some private members that should not trigger re-rendering.

```
class TestComponent extends AbstractComponent {
   protected additionalPersons = [];
   public state = {
     name: ""
   }
}
```

Let'a assume I added some values to `additionalPersons` array and changed the state.

```
additionalPersons.push("Jane");
additionalPersons.push("John");

this.setState({ name: "Boo" });
```

Then, I redirect to another component using react-router, so TestComponent gets unmounted and NewComponent gets mounted. After that I click "Back" button, and I go back to TestComponent.

Problem: I see the array in empty, state.name is "" because component constructs/mounts a fresh one.

What I want: I want to copy `this` before `TestComponent` gets unmounted, and mount it back when user comes back to this page again. (e.g I don't want react to create me a new instance, but simply use the previous one.)

Is it possible to do it with React?

Comment: You'd need to persist state to something like a global store, with say Redux. Or if you only have a few states, maybe save it in the URL?

Comment: Saving a previous instance of a component to reuse later seems like a serious anti-pattern. Just persist the state outside of the component, and use it to hydrate the component when it is instantiated. Something along the lines of `redux` seems like a good choice in this situation.

Comment: redux is fine, but so is just keeping state in a parent component.

Comment: You're looking for redux. Big code/complexity investment, but it's the most logical way to do what you're looking for.